# How to use mousePressed in ProcessingJS?

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I'm trying to access the [mousePressed](http://processingjs.org/reference/mousePressed/) property in a ProcessingJS snippet but am getting `undefined`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/processing-js/processing-js/processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('body').append($('<canvas id="preview"><p>Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</p></canvas>'));
    function onPJS(p) {
        p.setup = function(){
            console.log(p.mousePressed);//prints undefined
            try{
                console.log(p.mousePressed());
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e.name,e.message);//prints TypeError Property 'mousePressed' of object [object Object] is not a function
            }
        }
    }
    new Processing(document.getElementById("preview"), onPJS);  
});
</script>
```

Any clues on what I'm missing/doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm using a hacky workaround relying on jquery at the moment: `var mousePressed = false;
 $("#preview").mousedown(function(){ mousePressed = true; });
 $("#preview").mouseup(function(){ mousePressed = false; });` but I wish there is a better way to handle this with PJS only

Comment: Can you put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @benoît it's on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orgicus/qb5xp/) now, is that helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access sketch-internal variables, only functions. You'll have to write a getting function for it, and then it'll work.

```
boolean getMousePressValue() { return mousePressed; }
```

That said: you really don't. You can simply add a click, mousedown, mouseup listener to the canvas, which will give you the same information in a pure-JS way, which you seem to be doing anyway. Just use:

```
pjsCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){...},false);
pjsCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){...},false);
```

Done. No need to reach into the sketch for that information.

Comment: "can't access sketch-interal variables, only functions" didn't know that, thanks! I've started porting [a Processing sketch](https://github.com/twsu/brighteyes/blob/master/BrightEyesEditor/BrightEyesEditor.pde) and this is one of the things that didn't work as expected. When porting Processing code to ProcessingJS, what's the recommended route ? loading a pde, stripping out the unsupported and interfacing with regular js where needed or ProcessingJS from Javascript/as a js library rather than a converter/parser ? Thanks!

Comment: If it's working Processing code, I don't even bother converting it to native JS myself. As long as it doesn't rely on imports, Processing.js can convert it quite fine itself. If I need to tie the sketch and the rest of the page together, I just use an approach like I describe in http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html

Answer (score 2):

I answered this on your other question in passing. I've replicated that here:

GoToLoop at https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/issues/137 says that your problem with `mousepressed` is caused by the fact that to avoid name collisions in JS, the boolean `mousepressed` is called `__mousePressed` in JS. They recommend that you use Java syntax to code your app and have it automatically translated into JS, to avoid these gotchas.

Comment: ah!...quite a gotcha, thanks for pointing this out(+1). Will give this a shot when I get a chance

Comment: I wish I could give you 1,000,000 upvotes. Been trying for a long time to figure this out, and yours is the first real answer to this question.